# Target Unreachable when Access a composite key from JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jakarta-ee, composite-key

Inside my JSF I did

```
<h:outputLabel value="Group:" for="group" />
<h:inputText id="group" value="#{newUserController.group.groupKey.groupId}" title="Group Id" />
```

`Group.java`

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupKey groupKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;
    //setter, getter, constructors, equals and hashes
}
```

`GroupKey.java`

```
@Embeddable
public class GroupKey {

    @Column(name="userId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String userId;

    private String groupId;
    //setter, getter, constructors, equals and hashes
}
```

So when I try to persist the object, it give me this error

```
value="#{newUserController.group.groupKey.groupId}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

**EDIT**
Here is the content of my Managed Bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="newUserController") 
@RequestScoped
public class NewUserController {

    private User user = new User();

    private Group group = new Group();    

    @EJB
    DocumentSBean sBean;

    public void createNewUser(){
        user.addGroup(group);
        sBean.persist(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `#{newUserController.group}` or `#{newUserController.group.groupKey}` returned `null`. JSF will only set the **last** property (which is `groupId` in this case). If this is a template entity, you need to provide/preset a default and non-null value for `group` and/or `groupKey`. You can do this in for example the (post)constructor of the bean. If this is an existing entity, you need to ensure that those properties are properly prepopulated by JPA.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding

```
 @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     groupKey=new GroupKey();
 }
```

to the Group  Class, it will be initialized and it will not return null.

Answer (score 1):

The PostConstruct did not work for me (but I'm a newbie so take that for what it's worth). However, adding it to the entity class constructor did.

```
public Group() {
   this.groupKey=new GroupKey();
}
```